# What is the meaning of 来说更是如此 in 特别是对于那些体重减轻者和体重保持者来说更是如此?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

这项联合多所医学院校所做的研究发现，除了个别人以外，多数人体重的增加会从周六开始，而体重减轻则会从周二开始，特别是对于那些体重减轻者和体重保持者来说更是如此。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 16.

What is the meaning of 来说更是如此？

After searching dictionaries, I have reached here:

来说(concering or about)更(more)是(is)如此(this way / like this)

But it doesn't make sense, at least to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to know what came before this, because it seems a bit self contradictory.

多数人体重的增加会从周六开始，
the majority of participants will start to gain weight from Saturday,

那些体重减轻者和体重保持者
those who lost weight and those who maintained the same weight

Either: they gained weight, they lost weight, or they stayed the same. That is 100% of the participants, not 多数。

这项联合多所医学院校所做的研究发现，
This research, conducted in conjunction with various medical schools discovered,
除了个别人以外，
(that) apart from a few individuals,
多数人体重的增加会从周六开始，
the majority of participants will start to gain weight from Saturday,
而体重减轻则会从周二开始，
and will lose weight beginning Tuesday,
特别是对于那些体重减轻者和体重保持者来说更是如此。
this is especially so for those who lost weight and those who maintained the same weight.

特别(是): especially (don't need this 是)

对于[something]来说: regarding [something], concerning [something], as far as [something] is concerned

更是如此: even more so

Chinese likes to wrap phrases at both ends.

对于 [我] 来说，他是最合适的人。(I'm sure she's not talking about me!)
但对于 [我] 来说却是个好消息。
对于 [我] 来说，这是“第0步”。

Answer (score 1):

**对于(toward)** [n] **来说(regarding)** = **on the standpoint of** [n]

**对于** [那些体重减轻者和体重保持者] **来说** means:

- **on the standpoint of** [那些体重减轻者和体重保持者]

or

- **to** [那些体重减轻者和体重保持者]

The **对于** [n] **来说** structure opens [n] as a topic, and it has to be followed by a follow-up statement to make a complete sentence

Answer (score 0):

来说(concering or about)更(more)是(is)如此(this way / like this)

It is more likely true for those who have reduced their weight or kept it with no change.

对于什么什么来说更是如此 (It is more obvious, more likely true, more suitable to say that) is a sentence or phrase that people used very often to further demonstrate the correctness of the theory.

For example, 如果你不经常刷牙，你的牙齿就会腐蚀掉。对于少年儿童来说更是如此。(If you do not brush your teeth often, they will decay quickly. It is especially critical for children.)